# Houseplant Identification

Tags: identification, houseplants

I'm not sure whether I can ask this question here or not. For, I am attaching an image to be identified and it's not easily searchable. I bought [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6H5Y.jpg) lovely plant yesterday, but I don't know its name and how to maintain it.

[image: Peperomia]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This plant is [Peperomia obtusifolia](http://www.floridata.com/ref/p/pepe_obt.cfm), a native of Florida and Central America. You can identify it by the thick, fleshy stems and leaves which have a glossy wax finish. Flowers are insignificant but this if more than made up for by it's adaptability to being grown indoors or as an outside ground cover in tropical areas.
Does your plant have drainage at the bottom of the pot? You can always pot it up and put the pot inside the decorative pot.

- Indoor plants like filtered light an east window or well lit north window.
- they like a soil rich in organic matter. A soil less potting mix works well
- likes high humidity and moist but not wet soil.  Water and then let the top of the soil dry out.
- propagates easily from cuttings.  Cut a stem below the joint, let it dry out for a day and put in a rooting medium like damp vermiculite or perlite.
- overwatering can encourage diseases which show up as mushy black spots on the leaves
- can be attacked by scales or mealybug which can usually be controlled with a Q tip or swab soaked in soap and water

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree that this looks like Peperomia obtusifolia (and may actually be that), as kevinsky suggested, I think it's equally likely that it's a young rubber plant (Ficus elastica), by its appearance. Whatever the case, you should eventually find out by how large it gets. Rubber Plants get pretty large (and so do their leaves). They also have white latex in their leaves and stems. I don't know if Peperomia obtusifolia contains latex (but coincidentally, it is also known as a Baby Rubber Plant, notwithstanding it's not even in the same genus, let alone order).

Answer (score -1):

Indirect light, water once a week.  Mine is going on 2 years!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10525)

Comment: @J.Musser The last four words of the question are "how to maintain it". Doesn't this answer that part of the question?

Comment: Not in a useful way, @NiallC.